# Do wash sales rule disallow losses if 100% of the stock is sold, all on the same day, within 30 days of buying lots, and no new shares are bought?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, wash-sale

I bought multiple lots of stock A  on 3 separate days, each about a week apart, so I have buys on 3 days.  I sold all of it about a week later, and from the first buy to the final sale, less than 30 days elapsed.  I did not buy any shares of A after I sold shares.  My brokerage disallowed almost all of the losses, claiming they were loss sales.  I was advised by the tax person at the brokerage at the time that if I sold 100% of the stock on that day (I did), although the multiple lots would be reported as loss sales that I would be able to take the loss on my taxes by reporting it separately, showing 100% sold.
Since I did not buy anything after I sold the shares, and I sold every lot I ever purchased of the stock, can I still take the full short-term loss?  What do I do since the 1099-B reported a disallowed loss (about $500) that I think should not be disallowed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you end up with no position 30 days after the last transaction then all your loss would have been recognized. The disallowed loss goes to basis adjustment of the other lot, but since that was also sold - you got it recognized there.